# How to store information of multiple users, and have it displayed in other frames tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I found an answer relating to how I can access data from other pages, which is creating a dictionary in the SampleApp class, and then use the controller to let every page access that. However, my question is how can I have it so that if there are multiple users, how can I display their username and passcode in another frame? Or would it use the dictionary I created in the SampleApp class, accessing the data from the page I want to access it from?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family = 'Garamond', size = 18, weight = "bold", slant = "italic")

        #container we'll stack frames on top of each other, then the one we want to
        #visible will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = "True")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.shared_data = {"username": tk.StringVar(), 
                            "passcode": tk.StringVar()}
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, UserInfo, UserPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent = container, controller = self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            #put all of the pages in the same location;
            #the one on the top of the stacking order
            #will be the one that is visible
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.configure(background = 'teal')
    
#starting frame
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Sample App", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page One",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page Two", bg = "green", fg = "white", width = 10,
                        height = 4, command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))

        Exitbutton = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", width = 8, height = 3, command = self.Exit)

        button1.place(x = 200, y = 200)
        button2.place(x = 600, y = 200)
        Exitbutton.place(x = 350, y = 330)

    def Exit(self):
        self.controller.destroy()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "This is Page One", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top")

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Start Page",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page Two",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))

        button3 = tk.Button(self, text = "User Info",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("UserInfo"))

        button1.place(x = 200, y = 200)
        button2.place(x=400, y = 200)
        button3.place(x=300, y =340)

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "This is Page Two", font = controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side = "top", fill = "x", pady = 10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Start Page",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Page One",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()

class UserInfo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "User Info", font = controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side = "top")

        label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "User's Name", font = "Arial 13")
        label2.place(x=100, y=100)
        
        nameEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.controller.shared_data["username"])
        nameEntry.place(x=250, y=100)
        
        enterButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Enter", 
                                command = lambda: controller.show_frame("UserPage"))
        enterButton.place(x = 100, y = 350)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Go to Start Page",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button1.place(x=300, y = 350)
        

class UserPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "User Page", font = controller.title_font)
        label1.pack(side = "top")
        
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Page One",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.title("Sample App")
    app.geometry("800x500")
    app.mainloop()
```